# When will instruments process stop

Tags: instruments, xcode-ui-testing, xcode-instruments

Now I'm learning UI testing in Instruments. I want to know in what cases will the instruments process stop. Like when the App that is being tested crashes or something. Does someone konw?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use UI Testing based on XCTest instead of instruments and javascript. The javascript way of UI testing is officially deprecated.